# Use JQuery to fill value in hidden form and submit to get new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to go achieve the following steps:

1. Declare a hidden form in the html page.
2. Fill the value of a field in the form using Jquery.
3. Submit the form with post method with values that's I have set to call a PHP script so that the browser can be repainted.

My problem:

I am a novice of the web and dont have any clue to go about this.

Comment: Step 1: Read a tutorial on form handling using JQuery. Step 2: Profit.

Comment: Yeah I did but my intuition is failing me. But thanks a ton I actually got a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all if form is hidden you probably don't need form

you can simply post your values with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

in case you have form you can serialize it: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
and then post your values

Comment: Will this repaint the browser?

Comment: what do u mean by repaint? are you talking about refreshing page? using ajax main purpose is not to refresh page. if you want to submit form and refresh page you can do $(form).submit();

Comment: Thanks a ton. Pulled an all nighter but got around most of JQuery and Javascript :D . Basically used :
$('#genre').val(genre);
$('#formSubmit').submit();

Answer (score 0):

In that case you don't require to declare form. call ajax method of jquery and pass whatever parameter you want to pass.

```
$.post("{Your service url}", { Key : Value} , function () {
    // Do Stuff
});
```

Comment: The this is I want to reload a page. I think that most convenient way of repainting that is declaring a hidden form and then submitting it to get new page.